# Disable checkboxes in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Just want to ask if how can I disable the checkboxes from editing in my worksheet? My worksheet is locked but I can still check and uncheck the checkboxes.

Plus, I used the codes below to disable cells from selecting in the worksheet but I can still edit the checkboxes.

```
With ActiveSheet
  .protect
  .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With
```

Can someone help me? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: These are check-boxes that you've added either programatically, or via Developer -> Controls -> Insert check-box ... right?  If so, I'm pretty sure you would need to use VBA to disable the check-box controls - just protecting the sheet will not disable form controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disable ActiveX Checkboxes

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub disableCheckBoxes()
    Dim ole As OLEObject
    For Each ole In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(ole.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            ole.Object.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next ole
End Sub
```